# Application exits on process exited event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, process

I am making form application, that also runs a console process on different thread. Basically I need to unblock a button after application has exited. Before I made event handler the process after completion just stopped, but now, after event the applications itself is killed.

Here is the code for making process run:

```
public void CallConsole()//This Calls the console application
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
       p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
    p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
    p.Disposed += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
    p.Start();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

I tried to work with Thread.IsBackground property, but that didn't change anything

Here's the event handler itself:

```
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)//Process on exit or disposed will make button1 avalable
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Any ideas why the application after adding

```
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

is now killed, not just the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that

```
void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)//Process on exit or disposed will make button1 available
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

required invocation and did not have any sort of error handling. Once I added another function that checks `button1.InvokeRequired` and in case it does calls itself again trough invocation it worked out great

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `Exited` event is firing on a thread pool thread. Controls can only be modified on the UI thread.

You could call `BeginInvoke`, but it's simpler to just configure the `Process` object to invoke itself by setting:

```
p.SynchronizingObject = button1;
```

`Button` implements `ISynchronizeInvoke`, which the `Process` object uses to invoke its events.

Comment: I was looking for this kind of answer. Thank you so much.